# Connection problems: TCP Socket with QTcpServer and Android client

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

I'm trying to make a Socket connection via TCP protocol.

But my server (written in C++ and running on my PC) does not receive connection request from my client (written in Java and running on Android)

**ServerSocket.h (in my PC)**

```
class ServerSocket: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit ServerSocket(QObject *rpParent = 0);
    void initServerSocket();

    public slots:
        void acceptConnection();
        void startRead();

    private:
        QTcpServer* server;
        QTcpSocket* client;
};
```

**ServerSocket.cpp (in my PC)**

```
ServerSocket::SocketClient(QObject *rpParent) :
    QObject(rpParent)
{
    server = new QTcpServer(this);
    client = new QTcpSocket(this);
}

void ServerSocket::initServerSocket(){
  connect(server, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(acceptConnection()));
  server->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 6005);
    while(1){
        if(server->hasPendingConnections() ){   
            printf("hasPendingConnections...\n");
        }
    }
}

void ServerSocket::acceptConnection(){
  client = server->nextPendingConnection();
  connect(client, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(startRead()));
}

void ServerSocket::startRead(){
  char buffer[1024] = {0};
  client->read(buffer, client->bytesAvailable());
  printf("startRead %s\n", buffer);
  client->close();
}
```

**ClientSocket.java (in Android)**

```
public class ClientSocket {

    private Thread serverThread = null;

    public ClientSocket(){
        serverThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
    }

    public void sendData(){
        serverThread.start();
    }


    class ClientThread implements Runnable {
        private PrintWriter printwriter;

        public ClientThread() {
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.0.12", 6005);
                if( socket.isConnected()){
                       Log.e("sendData", "connected!");
                }             
                String msg = "Hey server!";
                printwriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                printwriter.write(msg); 

                printwriter.flush();
                printwriter.close();
                socket.close();

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Could you help me?

Comment: 'written in C'   ??? That is no C.

Comment: 'server ... does not receive connection request from my client'. Ok, but is there a connection established to begin with? What happens in the client? Can it connect? What are the errors?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I meant C++.  I do not get any error (on client side or server). In the client `socket.isConnected()` return `true`. But the server don't have pending connections

Comment: Why do you close client (**client->close();**) ? First (and every) invoke of startRead() may has zero (**or not enough**) bytes available